# Conditions when the log of Relative Risk is approximately Normal

Tags: normal-distribution, assumptions, odds-ratio, relative-risk

Under what conditions is the log of RR (or OR) approximately Normally distributed? Sources would be very much appreciated - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk#Inference) for example just states the SE formula but provides no information on **when** it is true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably confident this is just an assumption based on the CLT.

A distribution converges to a Normal whenever it's approximately a sum of a lot of fairly small, roughly independent values, positive or negative.

If a log-value is Normal, that indicates that it can be approximated as a *product* of a many such variables instead, as $\prod_0^ix_i = \exp(\sum_0^i\log(x_i))$.

Assuming the risk in both groups is >0 (even if it is very small), then $p(outcome)$ can often be modeled (especially in complicated systems, e.g. human body) as a conditional probability $p(outcome|v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$, which satisfies that condition given enough variables if there are no strong correlations unaccounted for.

Comment: The question should be how _useful_ normal approximations for these quantities are.  Exact Bayesian uncertainty intervals are available, as well as fairly accurate profile likelihood confidence intervals.